# Sample until a desired condition is met

Tags: sampling

Suppose I have a population of N elements. For the sake of example, imagine these elements take either a value of 1 or a value of 0. My goal is to estimate the sum of the N elements.

To do so, I wish to set a maximum standard error threshold, rather than set a fixed sample size, as is typically done in SRS. The idea is to sequentially select one element at a time, using SRS of n=1 for each iteration, estimate the standard error, and continue until the standard error threshold is met, then stop.

This of course is not SRS itself, since the number of collected elements will be random. The standard error made at each iteration is probably not unbiased for the true standard error either. Despite these shortcomings I see it as a potentially advantageous way to collect a random sample with little prior knowledge of the population standard deviation.

I am curious if this strategy has a name or has been studied before?

Comment: "*The standard error made at each iteration is probably not unbiased for the true standard error either*"  -- yes, in most situations it'd be (clearly) biased *downward*, since we're vastly more likely to stop when we underestimate the a standard error than when we over-estimate it (where we tend to keep sampling).